# Does libtool strip all options with -M?

Tags: c++, solaris, autotools, libtool, map-files

I'm trying to track down a failure to link with a mapfile on Solaris. The missing mapfile causes the following error when I try to run our self tests:

```
$ ./cryptestcwd v
ld.so.1: cryptestcwd: fatal:
/export/home/cryptopp/.libs/libcryptopp.so.6: hardware capability
(CA_SUNW_HW_1) unsupported: 0x4800000  [ AES SSE4.1 ]
Killed
```

I've gotten as far as this Automake rule. `libcryptopp_la_LINK`, which I believe is the shared object, is missing `AM_LDFLAGS`. `AM_LDFLAGS` holds the `-M cryptopp.mapfile` option.

```
libcryptopp_la_LINK = $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CXX $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) \
    $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=link $(CXXLD) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) \
    $(CXXFLAGS) $(libcryptopp_la_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

I tried to patch it with `sed` after `configure` runs:

```
libcryptopp_la_LINK = $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CXX $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) \
    $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=link $(CXXLD) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) \
    $(CXXFLAGS) $(libcryptopp_la_LDFLAGS) -M cryptopp.mapfile $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

I confirmed the `sed` is successful, but the same test fails again. When the commands are invoked `-M <mapfile>` is missing.

The [libtool manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html) talks about `-M` arguments on Cygwin, but not Solaris (and the discussion only applies to GCC, and not other compilers like IBM XL C/C++, Sun C/C++ and LLVM Clang):

> Note that you also need to ensure that the standard Unix directories (like /bin, /lib, /usr, /etc) appear in the root of a drive. This means that you must install Cygwin itself into the C:/ root directory (or D:/, or E:/, etc)—instead of the recommended installation into C:/cygwin/. In addition, all file names used in the build system must be relative, symlinks should not be used within the source or build directory trees, and all -M* options to gcc except -MMD must be avoided.

There is no other mention of `-M`.

And there is no diagnostic, like *"Removing `-M <mapfile>` options to Sun linker"* or *"Warning: `libtool` does not understand option `-M <mapfile>`"*.

My question is, does `libtool` discard `-M` and its arguments for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libtool does drop some link options when creating a library.  [The manual explains](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Stripped-link-flags.html):

> When creating a shared library, but not when compiling or creating a
> program, libtool drops some flags from the command line provided by
> the user. This is done because flags unknown to libtool may interfere
> with library creation or require additional support from libtool, and
> because omitting flags is usually the conservative choice for a
> successful build.

Personally, I find the justification for this behavior to be a bit cavalier, and I furthermore think it warrants a warning from `libtool` when it occurs, but unless you care to raise an issue against it, that's pretty much moot.

Experimentation shows that `-M` is indeed among the options that `libtool` strips.  In particular, if I specify `LDFLAGS` containing an `-M` option on the `make` command line then I can observe it echoed in the `make` output when it runs the `libtool` link, but not in `libtool`'s *own* echo of the link command that is actually executed:

> $ make LDFLAGS="-M mapfile"
>
> /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2  **-M mapfile** -o libmylib.la -rpath /usr/local/lib x.lo y.lo
>
> libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/x.o .libs/y.o    -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libmylib.so.0 -o .libs/libmylib.so.0.0.0

The `libtool` docs suggest two workarounds to pass link options that otherwise would be stripped:

- For *bona fide* linker options, you can use one or more `-Wl,` or `-Xlinker` options to pass your options through `libtool` and the linker driver to the linker itself.  For example,

  ```
   LDFLAGS=-Wl,-M,cryptopp.mapfile
  ```
- For options directed specifically to the linker *driver*, the docs suggest  adding the flags to the compiler driver command (CC="gcc -M mapfile"), but  ***this is ineffective*** because the `$(CC)` variable is expanded by `make` to form the `libtool` command line, leaving any options expressed in it exposed to `libtool` for stripping.

Additionally, however, there is

- The `-XCClinker` option by which options can be passed through to the linker driver (as opposed to the linker itself), but its behavior seems a bit quirky: it seems to ignore options that don't start with a hyphen (such as the name of your map file).

Comment: Thanks John. It tried `AM_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-M,cryptopp.mapfile`, but it was stripped it, too. (I don't mess with user `CXXFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`. Everything goes in either `AM_CXXFLAGS` or `AM_LDFLAGS`).

Comment: Thanks again John. *"unless you care to raise an issue against it, that's pretty much moot"* - yeah, that was done yesterday. See [Issue #29224: Solaris, lost mapfiles and silent failures](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2017-11/msg00000.html). The thing is, I'm not sure its a `libtool` bug. Another component, like Autoconf or Automake, may be stripping it. My guess is, nothing will be done now, just like nothing was done in the past. History has a penchant for repeating itself.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, @jww.  I tested with libtool 2.4.2, and when the libtool command line contained the `-Wl,` options, they were passed on to the link command, as advertised.  Neither `autoconf` nor `automake` could be stripping the flags, as the flags are never presented to them in the first place, and I am fairly confident that `configure` is not doing so.  Do be aware, however, that `AM_LDFLAGS` is ignored for targets that have their own target-specific linker flags (`libfoo_la_LDFLAGS`) defined.

Comment: Ack, thanks John. Here is the soup-to-nuts transcript: [Crypto++ and Autotools](https://pastebin.com/uSVqfn0d). It was produced by `autoreconf --force --install --warnings=all`, `CXX=/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC ./configure` and then `gmake -j 5`. I can't find any diagnostic stating requested options are being dropped. It occurs silently, even with `--warnings=all`.

Comment: Regarding `libfoo_la_LDFLAGS`, yeah I suspected that early. The actual uniform name (for us) is `libcryptopp_la`. Our [`Makefile.am`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools/blob/master/Makefile.am) has both `libcryptopp_la_SOURCES` and `libcryptopp_la_LDFLAGS`. I also tried adding a `lib_LTLDFLAGS` for our `lib_LTLIBRARIES` (is this even legal?), but it produced the same results.

Comment: @jww, your soup-to-nuts example appears to show `libtool` passing the `-M cryptopp.mapfile` options through to the linker driver (line 985).  That shows the actual command that `libtool` executes.  If libtool were stripping the options then they would still appear on line 984, but not on line 985.  Thus, if they are not being honored then it appears that that can only be a function of the linker driver, `/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC`.

Comment: Thanks John. The rule that is failing is the one on line 974, which begins with `libtool: link: /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC -G -hlibcryptopp.so.6 -o .libs/libcryptopp.so.6.0.0...`. There is no `-M cryptopp.mapfile` supplied for the recipe.

Comment: @jww at lines 973 and 974 we see that the `-M cryptopp.mapfile` are being presented as arguments to `libtool` but not passed on to the linker driver.  That is, `libtool` is indeed stripping them.  The recommended solution would be to instead present `-Wl,-M,cryptopp.mapfile` as an argument to `libtool`.  If there is a `libcryptopp_la_LDFLAGS` Automake variable then that's where that flag should be  recorded.

Comment: If that does not work -- which perhaps it won't -- then the hack you already described may be the best available solution.  If it happens, however, that the compiler permits concatenating those arguments into one then you could try instead passing the `-XCClinker -Mcryptopp.mapfile` option.

Comment: Thanks again @John. `-XCClinker` fixed the issue. Here are the former lines 973 and 974: [Crypto++ and Autotools (XCClinker)](https://pastebin.com/eD7M603Z). Now, the question for me... Why did `libtool` not get its options via `-XCClibtool` so all the `-M` options could pass unmolested? And why is dropping `-M <mapfile>` not producing a diagnostic? The dumb engineering decisions make me want to scream. Especially the ones that stay broke for two or three decades rather than being fixed.

Comment: @jww, I cannot answer "why" questions about `libtool`'s design, except by referring you to the manual.  I do agree that it seems a poor choice for `libtool` to silently drop options -- it ought to at least emit a warning about such drops, and ideally the diagnostic would include describing a mechanism for passing the options through.

Comment: The fix was committed at [91700386556c](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools/commit/91700386556c).